# Database initializer with EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I can't figure out why my initializers are not working. I am using EF Code First to create a database and also I want to use initializer approach to fill the database with default values when the database creating. But whenever I try, my database is creating but initializers are not working and there is no data in the tables which are the ones that I want to initialize with some default values. Am I missing something? If I am wrong, then what is the proper way of using initializers.
Note: I don't want to use Configuration.cs to seed my database, I want to use my custom initializers.
**DataContext.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Data.Context
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext 
    {
       public DataContext() : base("name=MyDB")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CategoryInitializer.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Data.Initializers
{
    public class CategoryInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
        }
        private static List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category {CategoryID = 1, CategoryName = "Category 1" },
                new Category {CategoryID = 2, CategoryName = "Category 2"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 3, CategoryName = "Category 3"}
            };
            return categories;
        }
    }
}
```

**Category.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Data.Model
{
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting a standard initializer instead of yours, it should be `Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CategoryInitializer());`

Comment: I did this too but not working.

Comment: You are missing `Database.Initialize(true);` after your `SetInitializer`statement. ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by *"I did this **too**"* -  this is requisite for your initializer being used at all. Now define "not working". When you use the code from the comment and put the breakpoint in your `Seed` method, it is called, right?

Comment: I applied Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CategoryInitializer()); and Database.Initialize(true); but still not works :(

Comment: Have you read my comment above? You are still missing `Database.Initialize` after your `SetInitialzer` statement. you set the initializer but never call it.

Comment: I added Database.Initialize(true); after SetInitializer @LocEngineer but not works.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DataContext to this:

```
public DataContext() : base("name=MyDB")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CategoryInitializer<DataContext>());
    Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

And your initializer to this:

```
public class CategoryInitializer<T> : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
{
    public override void InitializeDatabase(DataContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction
            , $"ALTER DATABASE [{context.Database.Connection.Database}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");

        base.InitializeDatabase(context);
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction
            , $"ALTER DATABASE [{context.Database.Connection.Database}] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
    }

    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
      //Do your stuff
    }
```

Also mind the `<T>` in the initializer. The two statements in `InitializeDatabase` are just to ensure proper migration.

Comment: PLease be a bit more precise as to "not working". Do you get an error? Have you enabled Migrations in the first place?

Comment: Wait a second, @RıdvanSÖYÜ, why do you have two different Namespaces between DataContext and Initializer? Actually: Why do you have THREE different namespaces??

Comment: I am not getting an error but the database is not flling with initial datas. Migrations is enabled. Also whenever I add a initial migration, it has no codes about initializing. Three namespaces are actually made by Visual Studio and i didn't edit because this is a test project. If I success, I implemented this to my original project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I am using class library for all data works. So to debug step by step, I changed output type of class library to windows application and for a test, I write a class. When I run the code step by step, it gave me an error message which is "unable to drop and create database in sql server". This means my database is on usage. Then I wrote a query "use master" and then I run again. And that's all. Problem is solved and my initializer is now working. Thanks, everyone!